# How to handle missing data in this case?

Tags: dataset, data-preprocessing

I'm practicing data cleaning on this very messy dataset on graduation outcome of a school, I attached some snapshots here:

[image]

[image]

There are a lot of cohorts that don't have the statistics, they seem to be missing completely at random, MCAR. However, since it also appears to follow a time series (every year from 2001 to 2006, plus 2016 Aug), I don't know if it is a good idea to remove these rows with missing data. The general goal is to do EDA on this, and I believe the year information is also important. If we remove them all, I think when we do aggregation to calculate certain statistics by year it will be problematic. (Note: deleting all these missing rows still leave a good amount of data). Please give me some advice on how to handle such situations, thank you!